# Add jars for mmlspark in spark classpath

Tags: maven, pyspark, jar

My requirement is to use `com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.12:1.0.0-rc3-43-54379bf7-SNAPSHOT`, in my pyspark application. I couldn't use --package and --repositories option since there is not internet connectivity in the deployment environment.
However, one this I can do is download the dependencies from maven and package everything in Docker image for deployment.

For downloading dependencies, I used:

```
mvn dependency:get -DremoteRepositories="https://mmlspark.azureedge.net/maven" -Dartifact="com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.12:1.0.0-rc3-43-54379bf7-SNAPSHOT"
```

This downloads all the dependencies in `/home/user/.m2/repository` location.

Now to use them in my spark application I tried few things:
1.) Extract all the jars Use `--jars /user/home/jar_files/*`, where I have copied all the downloaded jars.
==> However, this fails with an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: No main class set in JAR; please specify one with --class.
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.error(SparkSubmit.scala:968)
```

2.) Secondly, I copied all the necessary jars and copied them in `site-package/pyspark/jars/` location. And did my `spark-submit` command without any extra options. This failed with an error:

```
    from mmlspark.lightgbm._LightGBMRegressor import _LightGBMRegressor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mmlspark.lightgbm._LightGBMRegressor'
```

3.) I also tried using `--files` instead of `--jars`, but it didn't work as well.

I need help on how can I add these jars in my pyspark application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use `--packages` together with `--repositories` when submitting the application:

```sh
spark-submit --repositories https://mmlspark.azureedge.net/maven \
  --packages com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.12:1.0.0-rc3-43-54379bf7-SNAPSHOT \
  ...
```

Works just fine for me with `pyspark`

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.1.2
      /_/

Using Python version 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020 07:22:35)
Spark context Web UI available at http://...:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1629967436995).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> from mmlspark.lightgbm._LightGBMRegressor import _LightGBMRegressor
>>>
```

this will fetch necessary packages with their dependencies.  See [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management) for more details on customization of dependencies.

If you don't have internet connectivity, then you can simply point to the local Maven repository using the following option:

```
--repositories file:///home/user/.m2/repository
```

Comment: I can't use this as the deployment infrastructure doesn't have internet connectivity to download packages. Hence, I have to pre package everything in my docker image

Comment: updated answer with information how to run without external connectivity